# How to deserialize OpenNLP trained model?

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, opennlp

I'm using OpenNLP with Java to classify text. I have used `DoccatModel` object. Then I save it with the `serialize` method. I would like to know how to create the model from the `.bin` saved file.

Whitout that, I need to train the model each time that I launch the program.

```java
DoccatModel model = trainedModel(trainingDatasetPath);
serializeModel(model);
```

The method `trainedModel` returns a `DoccatModel` object trained by the file located at `trainingDatasetPath`.

Does anyone have any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer:
´DoccatModel´ has a constructor for that.

```
DoccatModel model;
if(model_file.exists()) {
    model = new DoccatModel(model_file);
} else {
    model = trainedModel(trainingDatasetPath);
    serializeModel(model);
}
DocumentCategorizer doccat = new DocumentCategorizerME(model);
```